# Can TextFieldParser in Microsoft.VisualBasic.IO Read Non-Breaking Spaces?

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I'm using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO TextFieldParser class to read a CSV containing two columns. The first column contains a character/set of characters to be replaced, and the second column contains the replacement character(s). Here is part of the file:

```
"ô","o"
"´","'"
"•","-"
"½","&#189;"
"Á","&#193;"
"ú","&#250;"
"à","&#224;"
"ê","&#234;"
"ì","&#236;"
"Ó","&#211;"
" ","&#160;"
```

The last entry is a non-breaking space (I verified this by checking in a hex editor and seeing the values `c2 a0`.

Here is my code for reading the CSV file:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> loadReplacementCharactersFromCsv(string filePath)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> replacementCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            replacementCharacters.Add(fields[0], fields[1]);
        }
    }
    return replacementCharacters;
}
```

I can't figure out why the non-breaking space is being loaded into the Dictionary as an empty string. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add parser.TrimWhiteSpace = false;

Comment: @HansPassant, that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to HansPassant for the comment, which resolved my problem.

By default, the `TextFieldParser.TrimWhiteSpace` property is set to `true`. This causes trailing left and right white space to be removed. In my case, I was trying to replace a non-breaking space with a regular space, but when the parser read the non-breaking space from the CSV file, it ended up returning an empty string since I did not reset the value of `TextFieldParser.TrimWhiteSpace` to `false`. The following modification resolved the problem:

```
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
parser.TrimWhiteSpace = false; // added so white space characters in CSV will be retained
```